# "Error: Could not find or load main class" - Visibility exception

Tags: java

I have the following code, which needs to be run by the HackerRank automated validator.

```
package stringrev;

import java.util.Scanner;

class str {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner in=new Scanner(System.in);
    int k=in.nextInt()+1;
    for(int i=0;i<=k;i++)
    {
      StringBuffer a=new StringBuffer(in.nextLine());
      StringBuffer b=a.reverse();
      System.out.println(b);
    }
  }
}
```

This code is working fine on my compiler but while uploading to Hacker Rank it shows an error:

> Error: Could not find or load main class str

What does that mean?

Comment: Please format your code next time. Also, you might want to update your question title to something more relevant.

Comment: Have you searched to find out if this is a common, easily-resolved issue with Hacker Rank? Or contacted them? The code seems fine, so this doesn't seem like a question that's suited to StackOverflow.

Comment: It seems like a hacker rank issue and not a java related one.

Comment: I don't know anything about Hacker Rank, but maybe you need to declare your class public by saying `public class str { ... }`

Comment: This question is not about `StringBuffer`. The title is irrelevant to the problem.

Comment: What's the file name? Try `public class Str`

Comment: Every comment and answer here covers that your class should be public. But for those who still face the same issue (probably cause we copy-paste from IDE, take note that you're **NOT** declaring the **package** in the first line. So ideally, your solution should start directly with the imports followed by the class Solution.

Answer (score 4):

HackerRank, as well as other automated websites, will take your code snippet and run it inside of another program (the automated validator).

The error you are getting is due to the fact that the validator tries to compile / access your code from within his code. Unfortunately, you have setup the visibility of your Str class to be default, which is not public!

If you change your code to:

```
public class str {...}
```

It should work. Also check that the name of the class is correct (it's unlikely that they ask you to have a lowercase class name).

Answer (score 0):

This error might happen if you add the package of the class, when you're copying the code from your editor to the  Hacker Rank. As an example, I had this error,

```
package hackerrank.RoadTransformation;

import java.util.*;

public class Solution{
...
    }
```

I removed the package **hackerrank.RoadTransformation;** part and the error was gone.